# How would I go about straightening my thick, african-american hair?

Tags: hair

Basically my hair is thick and unmanageable and I'd like to know what chemical products you would recommend for me to use to get it from an afro to straight hair (which I think is a lot nicer). I've seen videos on YouTube of men using hair relaxers and such but the issue is that all of them had had hair that was already way straighter than mine is even before using the chemicals. Honestly, my hair isn't super curly either, it's just too thick and I can't get a comb through it (well yea I guess it's just african-american hair). I'll try to post pictures.

How I'd like my hair to look

[image: Straight hair]

Similar to my hair now

[image: Afro]

Comment: @Willeke well when you have hair like the bottom picture I'd like to see you "learn to love it"

Comment: Almost nobody I know is happy with the hair nature has given them. Most of them learn to live with what they have been handed though. I am one of them, so I have it cut to a length I can live with. Turned out I rather love it that way.

Comment: Go to your local hairdresser and ask them. They can see your type of hair and have the experience to know what to do. They can recommend the right chemicals, or do it for you if you have the cash.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to say, you should learn to love your hair and what was given to you naturally, thats the real hack to learn.
The hack to learn to love what you have and what you are and not to try and change your self because of what society forces upon us as beauty through advertisements.
Because that beauty is fake.

Do you know how many bald people are in the world that would wish to have what you have on top of your hair and you want to put chemicals in your hair that will actually kill your hair, your scalp and endanger your actual brain and can cause a huge amounts of long term health effects as you age.
Do some research and look at what chemicals are in those hair straighteners and you will see its poison and a lot of people who constantly use such products end up in the long run with horrible hair, bald spots, burns and etc.

So love your hair bro that you were naturally born with and don't try to change one of the unique aspects about your self because then you will just be like everyone else and won't stand out in life.
Never follow the herd, always try to stand out and if you follow that concept you will notice that you will shine and always pick up all types of different women because your look is different and not common like all the other dudes trying to follow each other.

If you don't believe me then look at all the most successful dudes around, they all made sure they stood out and didn't follow the crowd.

Comment: Dude I'm 18 and I still haven't "learned to love my hair". I believe what you mean to say is "learn to deal with it" and not only is that not helpful but your entire post doesn't even attempt to answer the question I actually posed.